# Distance Vector vs. Link State routing

Tags: routing, protocol-theory, loop

Distance vector routing protocols have Split horizon & poison reverse for avoiding routing loops in the network.
  why the link state routing protocol not having that kind of measures and how the link state routing protocol avoid his loops?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

In link state protocols each participating router knows the whole topology of a network, which is stored in the link state database.  Using the link state database each router will calculate the best path to the destination.  The easiest way to think about it is as if with a link state routing protocol is that you give all your friends a map (the LSDB) and you tell them to find the shortest path based on mileage (bandwidth in the case of OSPF, not 100% about ISIS) to a given city.  As long as you all follow the map and the formula, you don't really need to worry about loops.

Comment: You still get transient loops during reconvergence.